# How to Make First Letter Upper Case without using Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have tried the code below and its not working

```js
function capFirstLetter(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ')
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const word = arr[i];
    word.toLowerCase()
    word[0].toUpperCase()
  }
  return arr.join(' ')
}
```

Comment: You have to assign the output of `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()`, they don't modify in-place

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Calling `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` on a string results in a *new string*. If you want to use that new string, you have to return it or assign it to something, or something like that.

Here, take the first letter and call `toUpperCase` on it. Then concatenate it with the rest of the letters which have `toLowerCase` called on them:

```js
function capFirstLetter(str) {
  return str.split(' ')
    .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase())
    .join(' ');
}

console.log(capFirstLetter('foo bAR'));
```